# Bigger icon just for one of the shortcuts on the desktop

Tags: windows-7, icons, desktop

On Windows 7 professional, I want a bigger icon just for one of the shortcuts on the desktop (only one program shortcut should have large icon, rest of the shortcut icons should be of the original/default size), is there a workaround like putting a **"clickable" jpg** onto the desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, icons on the desktop are all the same size and by default fit into a grid. You cannot have an icon with a different size.

What you *could* do is writing a little program that basically *appears* to be an icon and just let it never come on top of other windows. You could then proceed to do whatever you want if it's clicked.

Comment: good idea :) thanx